# ArrayList not preserved on pause

Tags: android, opengl-es, load, arraylist, onpause

My android game holds level layout data in an array list. While testing my level loader I noticed that sometimes my levels were failing to load leaving me with just a black screen.  At first I thought it might be my textures not re-loading but I proved this wrong by drawing an object separate from the ArrayList and it drew just fine. Next I used a Log tag to check the size of my ArrayList. As soon as I pressed home and then re-opened my application the Log tag started returning a size of zero meaning all my data had been lost. Now I don't really want to load my level data from file every time onPause is called so is there a way to preserve the data held in the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're probably getting garbage collected (i.e. you're pause is becoming a destroy because of memory issues). Implement the [onSaveIntstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) methods in your Activity to see if that solves the problem.

Num1 made a good point in the comment that I feel is worth point out. Note that bundles should contain small amounts of data. If your ArrayList is large, that's probably why your activity is getting garbage collected in the same place. If that's the case, you've got one of two options. Explicitly store the data on disk your self in the onDestroy method (that way you only do it when you really need to, writing to disk can take a while), or recalculating the stuff when your activity comes back into focus. This is just something good to think about.

Comment: anything special I have to do to get it back from the bundle or will it be there when the app resumes

Comment: I'm guessing the bundle itself is going to get trashed at some point but am I right in thinking that onCreate will be called again if that happens?

Comment: The bundle never get's trashed. When gc is done, the onSaveInstanceState is called and the bundle you write is saved someplace not in memory. When onCreate is called again (or onRestoreInstance), the bundle that you get in there will have the stuff you saved in onSaveInstanceState in it.

Comment: But don't take that as license to put a ton of data into the bundle! If the data can easily be regenerated throw it out, if there's a lot of it store it in a database. If it should persist between activities use Shared Preferences.

Comment: num1 makes a very good point. I'm going to add that to my answer.

Comment: Hmm interesting so why on earth do so many of the games on my phone return to the main menu and lose level progress when I leave them out of focus for a while?

Comment: Oops sorry just got num1's comments through. I guess it would suck if my SD card or phone memory was full of bundled junk from games

Comment: I've implemented the methods you suggested and I've found something really odd. When I press home I get a call to save and then I re-enter my app and even though there is no call to restore everything appears fine. Now when I lock my phone using the power button I get a call two save and a call to restore both at once and then the same again when I unlock my phone. Any clue?

Comment: An when I lock my phone a consistently lose my level data